# Changing aws credentials in hadoop configuration for pyspark during runtime after initialization of spark context

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I've looked around on Stack Overflow for solutions to related problem, but it seems that this one is fairly unique. For context, I need to refresh AWS security credentials every hour due to company procedures, and I'm struggling to add the new refreshed security credentials to spark. Everything works fine in the first hour (I can access and read tables from s3, etc), but I'm unable to successfully change my aws credentials after the first hour is up and the credentials are refreshed.

Once I refresh my aws credentials, here is the code that I'm using to update spark to make them use the new aws credentials:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext

def getAWSKeys(profile):
   awsCreds = {}
   Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
   Config.read(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), '.aws', 'credentials'))
   if profile in Config.sections():
       awsCreds["aws_access_key_id"] = Config.get(
           profile, "aws_access_key_id")
       awsCreds["aws_secret_access_key"] = Config.get(
           profile, "aws_secret_access_key")
       awsCreds["aws_session_token"] = Config.get(
           profile, "aws_session_token")
   return awsCreds


awsKeys = getAWSKeys(profile)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId",
                                 awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey",
                                 awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.session.token",
                                 awsKeys["aws_session_token"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.access.key",
                                 awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.secret.key",
                                 awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.endpoint",
                                 "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")


sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId",
                                 awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey",
                                 awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.session.token",
                                 awsKeys["aws_session_token"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.enableServerSideEncryption", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",
                                 awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key",
                                 awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint",
                                 "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")


sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId",
                                 awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey",
                                 awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.session.token",
                                 awsKeys["aws_session_token"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.enableServerSideEncryption", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.access.key",
                                 awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.secret.key",
                                 awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.endpoint",
                                 "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")

sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3n.enableV4", "true")
sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3a.enableV4", "true")

# sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.aws.credentials.provider",
#                                  "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")

os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = awsKeys["aws_access_key_id"]
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = awsKeys["aws_secret_access_key"]
os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = awsKeys["aws_session_token"]
```

I've attempted to be exhaustive in my approach, but sadly nothing has worked. The error that I get is:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-674174eca978> in <module>()
      3 table = (
      4     spark.read.option("delimiter", "|")
----> 5     .csv(f"s3n://{s3_path}/{file1}", header = True, inferSchema=True)
      6     .select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
      7 )

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in csv(self, path, schema, sep, encoding, quote, escape, comment, header, inferSchema, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, nullValue, nanValue, positiveInf, negativeInf, dateFormat, timestampFormat, maxColumns, maxCharsPerColumn, maxMalformedLogPerPartition, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, multiLine)
    408         if isinstance(path, basestring):
    409             path = [path]
--> 410         return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    411 
    412     @since(1.5)

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o12923.csv.
: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 9A4F6DDEA3BD8AA6), S3 Extended Request ID: xg9ZiPjfV3h4rGgs5emsUiWl8xQdv0OMhK/91qdAs/iIvapWgIlWh9m1qLTGj3ODFM9MtEnuueg=
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4169)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4116)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1237)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectMetadataCall.perform(GetObjectMetadataCall.java:24)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.GetObjectMetadataCall.perform(GetObjectMetadataCall.java:10)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:82)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:176)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:94)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AbstractAmazonS3Lite.getObjectMetadata(AbstractAmazonS3Lite.java:39)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1430)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.exists(EmrFileSystem.java:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:348)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:533)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

To reiterate, everything works fine in the first hour, but I get the 400 Bad Request error when I refresh the aws credentials. I've attempted to add these new aws credentials to spark, but nothing that I've tried has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see an easy way of doing this, as those credentials get bonded to the filesystem and then frozen.

If I were trying to do this, I'd write my own implementation of `AWSCredentialsProvider` which provides credentials for AWS calls. the default chain is something like: spark config, env vars, GET request to EC2 metadata service. You could add a new one which *somehow* picked up new values. You'd need to come up with a way of propagating the new session credentials to every host in the cluster though...hard work

The other thing is to know that AWS Assumed Roles have had their max life bumped up from 1 hour to 12 hours, so if you can get your IT team to increase the role you get assigned to 12 hours, you may just be able to get through the day.

Try that first.

ps: CSV "inferSchema=true" means "read through the entire CSV file once just to work out the schema". Avoid

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this one recently; after some digging in the hadoop-aws java code, found out:

- there is a cache (cache entry: URI, hadoop conf) of credentials provider that somehow does not work; when changing the hadoop conf (to change credentials) and reading a new file, it uses the provider cache entry when it shouldn't, hence using deprecated credentials
- there is a `fs.<scheme>.impl.disable.cache` (in our case, `scheme=s3a`) to disable this cache; this will instantiate a new credentials provider everytime, but at least you'll be able to create one with the new credentials